# why "spring-data-hadoop" need to make jar to avoid 'class not found exception'

Tags: spring-data-hadoop

I have read spring-data-hadoop reference docuements alot.
However, I cannot understand this framework architecture(or usage, necessary)

The most useful point I expected is programming map-reduce job on my local machine to run job on remote cluster. 
(Even In the spring-data-hadoop reference guid, It looks possible !)

In fact, I had to make jar including some mappers, reducers.., deploy (or copy) to on hdfs and then configure the jars to distributed cache as classpath.

like this

```
// '/tmp/test/classpath' is a path on hdfs
<hadoop:cache>
    <hadoop:classpath value="/tmp/test/classpath/*.jar"/>
</hadoop:cache>
```

at least I can understand that the jar including some classes needed to run job have to be deployed on hdfs. **But I cannot understand why 'spring-data-hadoop' doesn't provide automatic deployment.**

I read yarn localresources part and tried it. But it didn't work.
I guess mapreduce framework on 'yarn' doesn't support things(localyzer.. etc)

**Is there any good(useful) point of 'spring-data-hadoop'?**

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your use case is. Are you simply trying to run your own MapReduce job or is your job more complex. The <hadoop:job> has both `jar` and `libs` attributes where you can specify the local jars your job needs. You don't have to use the distributed cache. `libs` is a comma separated list of third party jars your mapper/reducer needs while `jar` would be the jar your build packages your mapper/reducer in.

Comment: I tried it a year ago, JAR attr worked well but A big problem that the perm space consistently increased each time JOB start to run existed. and LIBS attr didn't work. but this time I'm working on spring-data-hadoop-2.1 so I'll try again. thx for advise. after i get some more, I'll edit post with a bit more